# 8085 arithmetic program

Tags: programming-languages, assembly

Can I get the assembly language arithmetic program operations for 8 bit microprocessor programming ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The 8085 Instruction Set](http://www.cavehill.uwi.edu/fpas/cmp/online/el21c/lesson18.html)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.hobbyprojects.com/microprocessor_tutorials/8085_arithmetic_group_instruction.html

Source: Google